# How to save image chosen from assets Xcode swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I have a function that reverts my background image to its default image.

```
func revertwallpaper (sender: AnyObject) {

    if backgroundImage.image != UIImage(named: "image1") {
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "image1")

    }
```

It works as it should, except when I quit my app completely, the image changes back, it does not save itself.

How do I make it save?

Thanks

Comment: Save your image name in userdefaults and reset  launch or anywhere you want.

Comment: I'm new to coding, can you give me an example?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults check this . this will give you idea and learning too.

Answer (score 1):

Save it to a `NSUserDefault` and then set it from your `NSUSerdefault` again when you start your application again.

```
// Set
// forKey is the unique value to access the object you have saved
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("imageName", forKey: "key")

// Get
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key")
```

So for example, when you close your application do:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("image1", forKey: "key")
```

When you start again

```
let latestImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key")
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: latestImage!)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, do I put latestImage in viewdidload?

Comment: Yes you can do that, make sure to save the NSUserdeault whenever you update the image